# INSERT Error - IF file EMPTY function not working

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, insert

I have this code and for some reason I am getting this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB     server version for the right syntax to use near 's','Used','A Book','1','http://media1.' at     line 2
```

CODE:

```
if(empty($_POST['image'])) {
$file = 'http://media1.site.org/products/images/no-photo.jpg';

} else {
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/products/images/');
define('UPLOAD_HOST', 'http://media1.sabinalcanyon.org/products/images/');

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],UPLOAD_DIR.$_FILES['image']['name']);

$file = UPLOAD_HOST.$_FILES['image']['name'];
}

$descedit = "<p>".$_POST['description']."</p>";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (`title`,`barcode`,`ISBN`,`catagory`,`set_price_start`,`brand`,`condition`,`description`,`amount_stock`,`picurl`) 
VALUES('$_POST[title]','$_POST[barcode]','$_POST[ISBN]','$_POST[catagory]','$_POST[set_price_start]','$_POST[brand]','$_POST[condition]','$descedit','$_POST[amount_stock]','$file')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Line 2 is just the start of this block of code.

Comment: Wonderful. You have an error (and a gaping SQL injection security hole). We've all been there. Now, *what have you done so far to debug this*? (For starters, what is the query string generated?)

Comment: check your `$_POST[brand]` value.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). You are vulnerable to file injection attacks. **DO NOT USE THIS CODE ON A PRODUCTION SYSTEM**.

Comment: you are not escaping your inputs, which is why when one of them contains an apostrophe it breaks your query.

Comment: Just for the record, it's **"category"**, and not **catagory**. Let's keep good grammar alive! (wink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just give you an example and you continue with the other variables.

```
    VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."',.......
```

and about your error

```
    right syntax to use near 's' ,
```

this is due to `$_POST[brand]` variable.

i guess you have some values in your brand variable which includes apostrof `'s` 
then better to escape it like that

```
  '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['brand'])."'
```

- Please turn to `PDO` or `MYSQLI` as `mysql` is already deprecated.

Comment: It would be so nice if they (SQL) would of came up with an error message like this instead: **"You have an apostrophe in there, do something about it."** (lol)

Comment: :) , it will be nice like that , then all will understand it :)

Comment: Yeah, seems like they don't want to make it easy for anyone. Then again, who said programming was going to be easy(?) Well, I for one have learned something new today. *Peace*

Comment: Well thank you all for your input.  I will do my best to use what you have taught me!